# Formula of PRML(3.63)

Tags: pattern-recognition

I'm not good at English, so I apologize in advance.

I have a question in "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning",
and it is a formula which is described in ch3.3.3 and (3.63)

I dont understand how we can transform (1) to (2), 
could anyone teach me ??

$ cov[y(x), y(x')] = cov[φ(x)^Tw,w^Tφ(x')] =  
φ(x)^TS_Nφ(x') = β^{-1}k(x,x')$

Answer (score 1):

Let the prior $Q_0$ over the weights be given by the density function $$ P(w|\alpha)=\mathcal{N}(0,\alpha^{-1}I) $$
so that the posterior over the weights $Q_w$ given the training data targets $\vec{t}$ can be written (as a density)
$$
P(w|\vec{t}) = \mathcal{N}(w|m_N,S_N)\\
m_N = \beta S_N\Phi^T\vec{t}\\
S_N^{-1}= \text{cov}(w)^{-1}=\alpha I + \beta\Phi^T\Phi
$$
The predictive distribution $Q_p(x)$ (for input $x$) then has density computed via
$$
P(t|x,\vec{t},\alpha,\beta)=\int P(t|x,w,\beta) P(w|\vec{t},\alpha,\beta) dw=\mathcal{N}(t|m_N^T\phi(x),\beta^{-1}+\phi(x)^TS_N\phi(x))
$$
Thus the model predictions are distributed via $$y(x) = w^T\phi(x) \sim Q_p(x) 
\tag{0} $$ so the predictive mean is simply $$ y(x,m_N) = \mathbb{E}[y(x)] = m_N^T\phi(x) \tag{1} $$ 
Notice that the covariance of the weights under the posterior is given by
$$
\text{cov}(w) = S_N \tag{2}
$$
And that the following formula holds (for covariances of vector-valued random variables in general)
$$
\text{cov}(w) + \mathbb{E}[w] \mathbb{E}[w]^T = \mathbb{E}[ww^T] \tag{3}
$$
One more note (eq. 3.62 in the book):
$$ y(x,m_N)=\beta S_N\Phi^T \vec{t}=\sum_iK(x,x_i)t_i$$
$$\therefore \beta^{-1}K(x,x_i) = \phi(x)^TS_N\phi(x_i)\tag{4}
$$
Ok, so what is the covariance between our scalar predictions for two inputs?
$$
\text{cov}[y(x_1), y(x_2)] =  \text{cov}[w^T\phi(x_1), w^T\phi(x_2)]
$$
using (0). Then using the identity for covariance between scalars 
$$\text{cov}[s_1,s_2]=\mathbb{E}[s_1s_2] - \mathbb{E}[s_1]\mathbb{E}[s_2]$$ we get 
\begin{align} 
\text{cov}[w^T\phi(x_1), w^T\phi(x_2)] &= \mathbb{E}[\phi(x_1)^T w w^T\phi(x_2)] - \phi(x_1)^Tm_Nm_N^T\phi(x_2) \\ &= \phi(x_1)^T\mathbb{E}[ w w^T]\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)^Tm_Nm_N^T\phi(x_2) \\ &= \phi(x_1)^T\left[ \text{cov}(w) +  \mathbb{E}[w] \mathbb{E}[w]^T\right]\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)^Tm_Nm_N^T\phi(x_2) \\ 
&= \phi(x_1)^T  S_N \phi(x_2) + \phi(x_1)^T m_Nm_N^T \phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)^Tm_Nm_N^T\phi(x_2)\\
&= \phi(x_1)^T  S_N \phi(x_2) \\
&= \beta^{-1}K(x_1,x_2)
\end{align}
using (1) for line 1, linearity for line 2, (3) for line 3, (2) for line 4 and (4) for the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to comment on the previous answer but don't have enough reps to do so yet :) For the computation of the last step, it seems to me that it can be simplified by taking out $\phi(x_1)$ and $\phi(x_2)$ first (they are scalers), i.e.,

$$\mathrm{cov}[\phi(x_1)^Tw, w^T\phi(x_2)] = \phi(x_1)^T\mathrm{cov}[w, w^T]\phi(x_2) = \phi(x_1)^T\mathrm{var}(w)\phi(x_2) = \phi(x_1)^TS_N\phi(x_2).$$

So the derivation of 3.63 is more straightforward?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1692491)

Comment: It does constitute a more compact answer?